# Set NSTableViewCell edit

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

NSTableViewCell contents one NSImageCell and one NSTextFieldCell, When add a new cell to NSTableView, method

```
[tableView editColumn:0 row:100 withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

make NSImageCell as editing.
I want it focus on  NSTextFieldCell, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set NSImageCell Editable as NO;

```
[imageCell setEnabled:NO];
[textFieldCell setEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[tableView editColumn:1 row:100 withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

I think textfield in 2 column.